# Styling in xsl-fo

Tags: xsl-fo, dita

I have a problem with understanding styling in xsl-fo. Situation looks like that, I have a table, and I want to style labels for this table (for every row, its first entry). But only for one table. What's the best way to do it?

```
<table frame="none" outputclass="prefaceTable">
      <tgroup cols="2">
        <colspec colname="COLSPEC0"  colwidth="0.2*" />
        <colspec colname="COLSPEC1"  colwidth="1.0*"/>
        <tbody>
          <row> 
            <entry align="right">Copyright</entry>
            <entry ><p conref="copyright.dita#copyright/statement"></p>
              </entry>
          </row>
          <row>
            <entry align="right">Intended Purpose</entry>
            <entry ><p conref="intendedpurpose.dita#intendedpurpose/statement" ></p></entry>
          </row>
          <row>
            <entry align="right">Conventions Used</entry>
            <entry><p conref="ConventionsUsed.dita#ConventionsUsed/statement"></p></entry>
          </row>
        </tbody>
      </tgroup>
    </table>
```

EDIT AFTER SOLVED:

And had to be styled in xsl-fo. Basically with help of @Radu and @Kevin I managed to do that, but I had to change it a bit more, since we have DITA 2.0.1, which is also pretty much changed. But in most cases solution given by @Radu (with changing following-sibling to the preceding-sibling), and by @Kevin (of course with changing td's to entries) should work. In my case it didn't, because from what I saw, plugins that we have checking if its the last cell and other things like that, so it wasn't that easy to just overwrite cell.

Comment: That table must have an identifier of some kind (unless you want to style one, and exactly one, *random* table in your document). In your current table styling code (?), test for the identifier. This can be as simple as "the 5th table in your input", but best is to give it a unique attribute.

Comment: Yeah, ok. Thats understandable. So lets assume that our table have id "preface". How to style it, to not destroy all other things that dita have. Other way, how to add attributes to already existing logic? Maybe I am asking stupid questions, but I am still fresh in this topic.

Comment: Are you styling in pure XSL FO ... or are you getting XSL FO from XML and XSLT? Certainly if you are doing the latter and not the former there are clear(er) ways to do what you want. I am a bit confused because you talk about "one specific table" but in combination with XSL FO styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably set an @outputclass attribute on the table with a certain custom value. Then from the XSLT code you can match entries like:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/table ')][@outputclass='specialFirstCell']/*/*[contains(@class, ' topic/tbody ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/row ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/entry ')][not(following-sibling::*[contains(@class, ' topic/entry ')])]">
            <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="tbody.row.entry">
                <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="applySpansAttrs"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="applyAlignAttrs"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="generateTableEntryBorder"/>
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="tbody.row.entry__content">
                    <xsl:call-template name="processEntryContent"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This will apply to the second entry, isn't it? I am looking for first entry. I tried changing following-sibling to the preceding-sibling, but that way I removed every second entry from this table.

Comment: Ok, now I know why it didn't work. Its just the plugin that we use checking also for some additional things, which were not here. Anyway, your answer was correct - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what all you are working with. It would be much better if you posted some clear XML and XSL to work with. Let's say you are working with simple tags like table, tr and td.

Your special table is marked with @class='special' ...

In the match you would have for the cell descendant (assuming it is td), you would write:

```
    <xsl:template match="td[ancestor::table[@class='special']]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::td) = 0">
            <!-- your special cell -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- all other cells in the special table-->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I will paste some code on Monday. But to be honest I think that if I combine yours and @Radu answer, I will get what I want.

Comment: I edited my question to summarize the problem. Thank you for your help.